# OPENQUERY on SQL Server 2005 64bit behaves weird

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, 64-bit, openquery

I just recently moved a SQL DB from SQL2005 32 bit --> 64 bit. I am having an issue connecting to Oracle using the OraOLEDB.Oracle Provider.

I was able to install Oracle 10G Client , ODAC 64 bit. I was also able to add a linked server to the Oracle instance. I am able to run a query using the linked server name directly:

```
SELECT top 10 *
  FROM [DB0PBB0]..[DB0PBB0].[DM_CLICK]
```

So far it is good, however, the problem occurs when I try to use OPENQUERY. I tried the following:

```
select * from 
OPENQUERY(DB0PBB0,'select *  from DB0PBB0.DM_CLICK where Date_stamp <''24-Jul-09'' and Date_stamp >= ''23-Jul-09'' ')

SET FMTONLY OFF
select * from 
OPENQUERY(DB0PBB0,'select * from DB0PBB0.DM_CLICK where Date_stamp <''24-Jul-09'' and Date_stamp >= ''23-Jul-09'' ')
```

and I get only the column names, no rows :(

if I run this script:

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
select * from 
OPENQUERY(DB0PBB0,'select ''hello'' from dual ')
```

I get

> hello

My question is, has anyone tried running OPENQUERY against Oracle from a SQL05 64bit ? Any ?Idea why would I get only columns back instead of data? I tried the same query on another server with the same link and it worked, it returned rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are getting rows with the `SELECT * FROM DUAL` chances are that it is a query issue. Regarding your query one potential pitfall is that you are comparing what looks like a date column (`DATE_STAMP`) with a VARCHAR.

**You should not rely on implicit conversions to compare dates**. Instead you should use the appropriate explicit functions, for exemple:

```
select * from 
OPENQUERY(DB0PBB0,'select *  
                     from DB0PBB0.DM_CLICK 
                    where Date_stamp < to_date(''24-Jul-09'', ''dd-mon-rr'') 
                      and Date_stamp >= to_date(''23-Jul-09'', ''dd-mon-rr'')')
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Because of your answer, I was able to use the OLEDB driver instead of the OLEDB-ODBC Wrapper